# Change size axis plot in R

Tags: r, plot

Hello how to change size axis plot in R

```
plot(c(imf[1,]), ylim=c(-100, 100),type="l", col="blue")
```

And the result is
[image]

I want axis is sequence 1:36, not (0, 5, 10, 20, 25, 30, 35) but (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.....36)

Answer (score 1):

You should `axis`. But it is optimized to not overlap overlap previously drawn labels, so here I am playing with `cex` parameter (depends on you window size) to show all labels.

```
plot(1:36, rnorm(36), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, 1:36, 1:36,cex.axis=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the x-axis with `xaxt = "n"` and add it back with your own `axis`.

```
plot(runif(36), type="l",col="blue", xaxt = "n", cex.axis=0.7)
axis(1, at=1:36, labels=1:36,cex.axis=0.7)
```

[image]